# Forcing a redraw of Direct2D

Tags: c++, mfc, direct2d

I have a combo-box in MFC C++ application that I use for drawing. Now I am experimenting with Direct2D for drawing. However, I am not able to re-draw content after the initial drawing. Using the code below, my "OnAfxDraw2D" method is being called when the application starts and the Direct2D content appears as intended.

Later, when I want to return my combo box to the initial state, I call the DoD2D() method. If the method is implemented using the first option, it works as intended, but it sometimes produce an assertion error in Visual Studio (Winhand.cpp Line 208). If I use the second option of DoD2D() method - nothing happens (the graphical content is not drawn).

Am I missing something here?

```
RenderArea::RenderArea() : CButton()
{
    BOOL bUseDCRenderTarget = TRUE;
    EnableD2DSupport(TRUE, bUseDCRenderTarget);
}

void RenderArea::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CButton::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(RenderArea, CButton)
    ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_DRAW2D, &RenderArea::OnAfxDraw2D)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void RenderArea::DoD2D()
{
    if (!IsD2DSupportEnabled())
        return;

    // Option 1) Works, but fails an assertion in debug mode
    Invalidate();
    return;

    // Option 2) Does not work.
    CDCRenderTarget *pRenderTarget = GetDCRenderTarget();
    pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
    DrawD2DResource(pRenderTarget);
    pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
}

void RenderArea::DrawD2DResource(CDCRenderTarget* pDCRenderTarget)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(pDCRenderTarget);

    D2D1_COLOR_F crBack =
        CRenderTarget::COLORREF_TO_D2DCOLOR(::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW));
    pDCRenderTarget->Clear(crBack);

    CD2DSizeF sizeTrans(0.f, 105.f);
    pDCRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(sizeTrans));

    CD2DEllipse ellipse(CD2DRectF(10.f, 10.f, 200.f, 100.f));
    CD2DSolidColorBrush brush(pDCRenderTarget, ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));
    pDCRenderTarget->DrawEllipse(ellipse, &brush);
    CD2DPointF pointFrom(10.f, 10.f), pointTo(200.f, 100.f);
    pDCRenderTarget->DrawLine(pointFrom, pointTo, &brush);

    pDCRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::IdentityMatrix());

    return;
}

LRESULT RenderArea::OnAfxDraw2D(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CDCRenderTarget* pDCRenderTarget = (CDCRenderTarget*)lParam;
    ASSERT_KINDOF(CDCRenderTarget, pDCRenderTarget);

    DrawD2DResource(pDCRenderTarget);

    HRESULT hr = pDCRenderTarget->EndDraw();

    return static_cast<LRESULT>(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: The debug assertion dialog has instructions on getting more information. If you debug the application, the IDE will take you right to the assertion that fails. That gives you hints as to which condition failed. Very helpful to you or anyone else who is trying to help. The callstack at the point of failure is also very valuable information. You should add both details to your question.

Comment: What happens on Invalidate (), do you have WM_PAINT handler somewhere? Regarding option 2, you'll need to call BIndDC at some point.